# WSO2 BAM-Custom events in Dashboard

Tags: wso2, wso2-bam

I am working with dashboard and want custom events to be shown using dashboard. Is it possible to see custom events using this?

Comment: What do you mean by Custom Events?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can do this. WSO2 BAM is designed to receive events and store in Apache Cassandra,has the capability to summarise the collected data by Apache Hive/Hadoop and writes the RDBMS database. By default h2 is used to write the data.

You can write the [jaggery application](http://jaggeryjs.org/) or you can use [gadget generation tool](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/BAM201/Gadget+Generation+Tool). Or any other third party dashboard which you want to be integrated also can be done as far as it can read it from RDBMS for which you are writing back the summarised data.